# How to reorganize output result in columns

Tags: python, python-2.7

My code Is reading from a text file that has a list of numbers separated by commas. If there is a whitespace and/or tab then it will detect it. My code runs good but now I want to make it look organized and better to read for my output file that it writes to.

Code:

````
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile
def pain():

    print("\t\t\tinput_files.zip has been unzipped")
    with ZipFile('input_files.zip', 'r') as zipObj:
        zipObj.extractall()
        listOfFileNames = zipObj.namelist()
        for fileName in listOfFileNames:
            if fileName.endswith('.txt'):
                zipObj.extract(fileName, 'storage')


    outfile = "output2.txt"                 #this will be the filename that the code will write to 
    baconFile = open(outfile,"wt")
    file_name1 = "file.txt"
    print('Filename\tLine\tnumber of numbers\tstring separated by a comma\twhite space found\ttab found\tcarriage return found\n')         #This prints the master column in the python shell and this is the way the code should collect the data 
    baconFile.write('Filename\tLine\tnumber of numbers\tstring separated by a comma\twhite space found\ttab found\tcarriage return found\n') #This prints the master column in the output file and this is the way the code should collect the data

    #for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd() + "/input_files"):
    for filename in os.listdir('C:\Users\M29858\Desktop\TestPy\Version10\input_files'):
        with open("input_files/" + filename, 'r') as f:
            if file_name1 in filename:

                output_contents(filename, f, baconFile)
    baconFile.close()       #closes the for loop that the code is writing to


def output_contents(filename, f, baconFile):     #using open() function to open the file inside the directory
    index = 0
    for line in f:
                                        #create a list of all of the numerical values in our line
        content = line.split(',')       #this will be used to count the amount numbers before and after comma
        whitespace_found = False
        tab_found = False
        false_string = "False (end of file)"
        carriage_found = false_string 
        sigfigs = ""

        index += 1                            #adds 1 for every line if it finds what the command wants

        if " " in line:                         #checking for whitespace
            whitespace_found = True
        if "\t" in line:                        #checking for tabs return
            tab_found = True
        if '\n' in line:                    #checking if there is a newline after the end of each line
            carriage_found = True                                        
        sigfigs = (','.join(str(len(g)) for g in re.findall(r'\d+\.?(\d+)?', line )))    #counts the sigsfigs after decimal point 

        print(filename + "\t{0:<4}\t{1:<17}\t{2:<27}\t{3:17}\t{4:9}\t{5:21}"
              .format(index, len(content), sigfigs, str(whitespace_found), str(tab_found), str(carriage_found)))   #whatever is inside the .format() is the way it the data is stored into
        baconFile.write('\n')
        baconFile.write( filename + "\t{0:<4}\t{1:<17}\t{2:<27}\t{3:17}\t{4:9}\t{5:21}"
                        .format(index, len(content), sigfigs, str(whitespace_found), str(tab_found), str(carriage_found)))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    pain()```


My filename text file:
```none
1.0,    1.023, 1.45
1.0,1.023,1.45
1
````

Master column: file name (tab) Line (tab) number of numbers (tab) string of “sigfigs” separated by a comma (tab) white space (tab) tab (tab) carriage return found

Expected output file:

````
expected:
```none
Filename    Line    number of numbers    string of “sigfigs/decimal Places” separated by a comma    white space found    tab found    carriage return found    
filename    1            3                       1,3,2                                                    TRUE              FALSE               TRUE        
filename    2            3                       1,3,2                                                    TRUE              FALSE               TRUE
filename    3            1                       1                                                        FALSE             FALSE               FALSE
````

actual:

```
Line 1:   1 3   2 tab detected,  White Space Detected, 
Line 2:   1 3   2 No Error
Line 3:   0 Missing carriage return,  No Error
Numbers in Line 1: 3
Numbers in Line 2: 3
Numbers in Line 3: 1
Number of lines: 3
```

Comment: This is the final code, I works fine now, it stores them in columns now

Answer (score 1):

You just have to save all you values in a table. When you finish processing your file, just iterate over a loop to create a [formatted String](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) which you will save in you file.

To center your values, just use the symbol `^` followed by the space between the columns. Below I made an example for a similar desired output:

```
tabled = [
    ['Filename', 'Line', 'number of numbers', 'string separated by a comma', 'white space found', 'tab found', 'carriage return found'],
    ['filename', '1', '3', '1, 3, 2', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE'], 
    ['filename', '2', '3', '1, 3, 2', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE'],
    ['filename', '3', '1', '1', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE']
]

for row in tabled:
    print("{: ^30} {: ^30} {: ^30} {: ^30} {: ^30} {: ^30} {: ^30}".format(*row))
```

Which gives the output:

```
   Filename                         Line                    number of numbers         string separated by a comma         white space found                  tab found                carriage return found     
   filename                          1                              3                           1, 3, 2                          TRUE                          FALSE                           TRUE             
   filename                          2                              3                           1, 3, 2                          TRUE                          FALSE                           TRUE             
   filename                          3                              1                              1                            FALSE                          FALSE                           TRUE
```

Comment: That is useful if my data was already inputted the way you have it but I am reading it from a text file and writing it to an output file.

Comment: Is there a problem saving everything in a table first, instead of printing to your output file straight away? I can't see why not do that in your case, just need to restructure your code a little bit.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean like have the format in the beginning then I have my code fill in the spots right??

Comment: Better to think like a code with two steps: The first step you have to read the input file, process the data, and feed the table. When you finish that, the second step you read the table, create the formatted string and write the output file.

Comment: Mmmm I see, okay I will work towards that path then and try to format the string andd write the output file. Thanks you got me thinking now

Comment: I would appreciate if you could accept my response as answered. It would help me a lot =)